# How can I update bugzilla entries from GitHub?

Tags: perl, git, github, bugzilla

I really only want to be able to add a link to the commit whenever a bug number is used in the commit message. Being able to close bugs and so on would be a plus, but really beyond my needs.

We generally prepend the bug number in the form of *xxxx* on the commit message.

My current plan was to use the email_in.pl script that ships with Bugzilla and an email post-commit hook on github. The email hook sends a payload with the details of each commit. I could parse that re-direct it to the email_in.pl script. Is this the best approach? Has nobody done this yet?

Any help/tips/links would be appreciated.

Comment: What about using the [Post-Receive URLs hook](http://help.github.com/post-receive-hooks/)?

Comment: what is your suggestion? That I write a script to parse the JSON and send the email?

Comment: That you have github post to your bugzilla server, and using [JSONRPC](http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/3.6/en/html/api/Bugzilla/WebService/Server/JSONRPC.html), update the bug that way. Not sure if it would work, but in theory, it should...

Comment: Thanks. JSONRPC would probably have worked, by just parsing the payload and hitting the URL. Since I had email_in.pl set up, but not the JSON API, I went with what you see below. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I had email_in.pl already set up, I decided to write a little script that would parse the URL post-receive hook's payload and send it in as an email to bugzilla. So a post-receive hook will hit a URL that does the following:

```
<?php
$payload = json_decode($_REQUEST['payload']);

if ($payload) {
    // assumes you want to process all commits (we only commit to the master branch)
    // but you may want to add some other conditionals above.
    $commits = $payload->commits;

    // there may be many commits per payload
    foreach ($commits as $commit) {
       $message = $commit->message;
       preg_match('/^(\*(\d+)\*)(.*)/i', $message, $matches);
       // The commit message must match the above regex
       // i.e. *1234* commit message
       if ( !(is_array($matches) && count($matches) == 4) )
          continue;

        $bugNumber = $matches[2];
        $comment = trim($matches[3]);
        $url = $commit->url;

        // get the author info
        $author = $commit->author;
        $authorName = $author->name;
        // assumes github email address exists in bugzilla.
        $authorEmail = $author->email;

        // construct the email
        $subject = "[Bug $bugNumber]";
        $body = "$comment\n$url";
        $header = "From: $authorName <$authorEmail>";
        // $bugzillaEmail = 'your@bugzilla.email
        mail($bugzillaEmail, $subject, $body, $header);
}
?>
```